# How to get the value of a variable from parsed HTML using Jsoup

Tags: java, angularjs, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to get the html of a [weather station](https://weather.com/weather/today/l/USTX1177:1:US). When i'm on the weather page and i right click the page and inspect it, within the DOM i see the element i want which is

```
<span data-gm-wx-temperature="::todayWxcardVm.obs.temperature" data-text-to-replace="77"><!-- ngIf: tempPrefix --> <!-- ngIf: hasValue --><span data-ng-if="hasValue" class="dir-ltr" data-ng-bind="temp | safeDisplay">77</span><!-- end ngIf: hasValue --><!-- ngIf: hasValue --><sup data-ng-if="hasValue" class="deg dir-ltr">°</sup><!-- end ngIf: hasValue --><!-- ngIf: showTempUnit -->
    <!-- ngIf: !hasValue --></span>
```

I want to be able to get the value of the temperature within the data-text-to-replace ="77", but my problem is Jsoup returns me this:

```
<span data-gm-wx-temperature="::todayWxcardVm.obs.temperature" data-text-to-replace="{{ '[[ obs.temperature ]]'.indexOf('\[\[') !== -1 ? '--' : '[[ obs.temperature ]]' }}">[[ obs.temperature ]]</span>
```

Where, instead of having data-text-to-replace="77" i get data-text-to-replace={{ '[[ obs.temperature ]] }}' which i'm assuming is the angular.js variable the creator of the website used to store the value of the temperature.

How would i get the actual value of obs.temperature?

Comment: What is the current code your using to extract the value you want?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166949/unable-to-retrieve-temperature-value-from-html-using-beautifulsoup-module-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you're not able to extract temperature value is because it's not sent in the `HTML` from the `weather.com`. Instead it's populated at the client by using value obtained via an `AJAX` call to `api.weather.com`.

You can directly call this web service from your Java client, but **I don't think that would constitute a legal use of the service** as I can see an `API Key` in the service input.

Following is a sample web service request with `weather.com` API key.

```
https://api.weather.com/v2/turbo/vt1precipitation;vt1currentdatetime;vt1pollenforecast;vt1dailyForecast;vt1observation?units=e&language=en-US&geocode=30.51,-97.68&format=json&apiKey=c1ea9f47f6a88b9acb43aba7faf389d4
```

If we say that `output` is the `JSON` response, then following will give you the temperature.

```
output.vt1observation.feelsLike
```

A sample `output.vt1observation` is below.

```
{
   "altimeter":29.86,
   "barometerTrend":"Rising",
   "barometerCode":1,
   "barometerChange":0.01,
   "dewPoint":74,
   "feelsLike":77,
   "gust":null,
   "humidity":91,
   "icon":29,
   "observationTime":"2016-08-13T21:05:00-0500",
   "obsQualifierCode":null,
   "obsQualifierSeverity":null,
   "phrase":"Partly Cloudy",
   "precip24Hour":0.29,
   "snowDepth":0.0,
   "temperature":77,
   "temperatureMaxSince7am":97,
   "uvIndex":0,
   "uvDescription":"Low",
   "visibility":10.000,
   "windSpeed":1,
   "windDirCompass":"N",
   "windDirDegrees":0
}
```